# deletion of objects using realm is not working

Tags: android

I am using realm version 3.1.1. I want to delete the object using realm data base and I have written the following code but it did not clear the object; object retains the old value.

```
realm.beginTransaction();
RealmResults<User> results1 =realm.where(User.class).findAll(); 
results1.deleteAllFromRealm();
realm.commitTransaction();
```

I am not able to delete the object using `deleteAllFromRealm` method. How should I do this?

Comment: improved capitalization, grammar slightly and code layout

Comment: did you get this working? started not being able to delete here too

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have initialized database instance. or configured correctly.

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
```

No needs to get Model object you can directly delete data from any realm Model

as below,

```
realm.beginTransaction();
realm.where(User.class).findAll().deleteAllFromRealm();
realm.commitTransaction();
```

don't forget to close realm on destroy of activity or fragment..

```
realm.close();
```

Comment: dang I closed mine forgot to commitTransaction()...thanks for the reminder

Comment: no one of the examples i found, actually work anymore

Answer (score 0):

try with following code, it might work.

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                try {
                    RealmResults< User > users=realm.where(User.class).findAll();
                    if (users.size() > 0) {
                        users.deleteAllFromRealm();
                    }
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code as below:

```
realm.beginTransaction();
realm.clear(User.class);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

This will find and delete all objects of User class.

Hope it helps!

Comment: no one of the examples i found, actually work anymore